# iPhone to iPhone Ready bluetooth device

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I Have an iPhone read bluetooth microcontroller that I can connect to and transfer data to using the app provided by the manufacturer. I have received the API documentation on how to send and recieve data however not how to pair and establish connection.

To my understanding iPhone does not support SPP, so my question is if a device is part of the MFI program how can I write an app to communicate with this device?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pairing and establishing connection is via the Settings -> General -> Bluetooth options on the iPhone.
Once paired the iPhone can connect to the device from the same menu manually or you can have the device automatically connect to the iPhone at any time of its choosing.

The MFi details are under NDA and cannot be discussed here. You can become part of the program for free and get the required details from Apple.
https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/